# Table not displaying a data from model

Tags: django, django-views

this is my views.py

```
def sms(request):
    obj = Sms.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'advisory.html', {'sms': obj})
```

and this is on my html.

```
    {% for i in sms %}
    <tr>
         <td>{{ i.description }}</td>
         <td>{{ i.timestamp }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

this is the model

```
class Sms(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And i don't really know why its not returning any data from my model. please help! thanks

Comment: Are there definitely Sms objects already in the database? Please could you also share your models.py? The code in your original answer looks fine, so I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: yes, i edited it.

Comment: Thank you, that matches up as I'm sure you knew! Are there definitely Sms objects already in the database? Can you see them in the /admin area?

Comment: Yes I checked the django admin, it is there and it have data samples.

Comment: Great. Ok, are you looking at the correct URL? The one that is connected to views.sms? Furthermore, is the HTML in your question, from 'advisory.html'?

Comment: I am also wondering if you have 'sms' defined somewhere else (e.g. in context_processors.py) which is overriding your work in the view.

Comment: Something else to check: if you add print(obj) after your obj = Sms... line, what do you see in your terminal when loading the page?

Comment: context_processors under TEMPLATE in settings.py right? no there's no sms there.

Comment: Hello, theres nothing on the terminal when i print(obj). I think its not getting to its destination. from views.py to templates folder?

Comment: btw, I'm using Bulma CSS. do you think it can affect?

Comment: Please could you add your urls.py to the question?

Comment: hello, i haven't added yet the sms from my views.py to urls.py. should I? because its not on a view tag.

Comment: Yes I think you should. This is what tells Django to run your view code, when you visit a particular URL. What URL are you visiting to test this by the way? Just localhost:8000? Here's some info about URLs in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thank you for answering, im near on giving this up. hahaha i can't trace the problem. is there any tracker error for django in pycharm?

Comment: btw, I also setup some serializers on my django because im using rest. any chance that it does affect?

Comment: Hello, I tracked down the problem, the urls are in the admin url not in the app. I transfered the urls into the app url. now it works,

Answer (score -1):

add to you Sms model function like this

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.description
```